# Travis CI build Racket Installation for Container-based

Tags: bash, build, continuous-integration, racket, travis-ci

My `before_install` in my `.travis.yml` reads

```
before_install:
  - . scripts/get_racket.sh
  - alias racket="${RACKET_DIR}/bin/racket"
```

I also have a script `get_racket.sh` which reads

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z "$RACKET_VERSION" ]]; then
    echo "Racket version environment variable not set, setting default"
    export RACKET_VERSION=HEAD  # set default Racket version
    echo "Version: $RACKET_VERSION" 
fi

if [[ -z "$RACKET_DIR" ]]; then
    echo "Racket directory environment variable not set, setting default"
    export RACKET_DIR='/usr/racket'  # set default Racket directory
    echo "Directory: $RACKET_DIR" 
fi

if [ ! -e cache ] || [ ! -d cache ]; then
    echo "Creating cache folder ..."
    mkdir cache
fi

cd cache

INSTALL=$(ls | grep '^racket*.sh' | tr -d '[:blank:]')
if [[ ! -e "$RACKET_DIR" ]] || [[ ! -d "$RACKET_DIR" ]]; then
    if [[ -z "$INSTALL" ]]; then
        echo "Racket installation script not found, building."

        if [ ! -e travis-racket ] || [ ! -d travis-racket ] \
        || [ ! -e travis-racket/install-racket.sh ] \
        || [ ! -f travis-racket/install-racket.sh ]; then
            git clone https://github.com/greghendershott/travis-racket.git
        fi
        bash < travis-racket/install-racket.sh
    else
        "./$INSTALL"
    fi
fi

which racket &>/dev/null
ESTATUS=$?
if [[ -n "$ESTATUS" ]]; then
    echo "Adding racket to PATH"
    export PATH="${PATH}:${RACKET_DIR}/bin"
fi

alias racket='$RACKET_DIR/bin/racket'

cd ..
```

but in a script that uses racket later in my build chain, I keep getting

```
 racket: command not found
```

As you can see in the above snippets, I have tried a few workarounds to install (and later cache for faster builds) racket without sudo privileges (because this is a restriction of Travis CI's Container-based infrastructure). Any help would be much appreciated, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out whether this install script you've shown successfully puts a working Racket binary anywhere on the disk. Maybe it didn't even compile, or maybe it tried to install in /usr/bin, where you don't have write access without sudo, or maybe there's something wrong with the binary. Find the binary, make sure it works.

If it does work, you need to pay attention to *where* your script puts Racket. Does it go to /usr/bin, $HOME, or someplace else entirely?

Finally, you need to figure out where the failing script is looking for Racket. The line where you set the $PATH will not affect the $PATH as seen from another shell script. I'd bet it's installing somewhere that's not in the default $PATH, and your failing script is looking only in the default $PATH.

Comment: Francesco: My [.travis.yml sets `RACKET_DIR` to `~/racket`](https://github.com/greghendershott/travis-racket/blob/master/.travis.yml#L9-L15) for [my `.install-racket.sh` to use](https://github.com/greghendershott/travis-racket/blob/master/install-racket.sh#L39-L43). But it looks like: (1) You're not setting it from your script and you default to `/usr/racket`?  (Which will fail w/o sudo.) And (2) You're not adding that to `PATH` back in your .travis.yml?

Comment: p.s. I sympathize. I don't have a lot of shell script experience, and it's tough to get things working in the Travis env.  I welcome pull requests.

Comment: I had the script default `RACKET_DIR` to `/usr/racket` so I could also use it outside of my Travis build. You were right though, it was a location issue, and it's fixed now.

Calling `. scripts/get_racket.sh` actually also results in setting the $PATH variable  properly (it's a workaround for `source scripts/get_racket.sh` -- try it locally -- but Travis does not have `source`, I've tried)

(My purpose of using the script was so I could cache both the install script and racket between builds. I'll submit a PR with the fixed script later today)